# How to write junit test cases for Jersey rest with spring dependency injection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jersey-2.0

I have web application which uses technologies like spring , hibernate and Jersey Jax-rs rest for web sevices.
I can write the junit test cases for Dao layer as well as Service layer  but i am not able to write junit test cases for jersey Rest which internally injects spring components.
Can anyone help ? 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RestAssured for rest unit tests

You can find detail explanation in there

http://rest-assured.io

Sample Rest Unit Test from my own trial

```
@Test
public void createEntityShouldReturnCreated() throws Exception {
    given().port(DemoApplicationTests.serverPort).contentType("application/json").body(detailDto).when()
            .post("/api/employee").then().statusCode(201)
            .header("X-demoApp-alert", "demoApp.entity.created");
}
```